# Зачем использовать "|=", "&=" и т.п. в C++ вместо "="?

Tags: c++, операторы

Програмлю Arduino и читаю в интернете про PORT. Говорят, что какая-то там стабильность будет, если писать вместо `=` - `|=`, или `&=`.
Так я так и не понял, для чего так писать и чем это отличается от обычного "равно"?
Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
int main() {

DDRB = B00100000;

while(1) {
    PORTB |= B00100000;
    delay(1000);
    PORTB &= B00000000;
    delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Если заменить все эти `|=`, и `&=` на `=`, то всё будет работать точно также (как мне кажется) и даже не изменится размер прошивки (скетча). Так возвращаемся к вопросу: ***Зачем "|=", "&=" и т.д. в c++***?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если вопрос касается именно `c++` - то это операторы.

`|=` - побитовое **или** с присвоением.
`&=` - побитовое **и** с присвоением.

Подробнее про операторы [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B2_C_%D0%B8_C%2B%2B#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

По сути, это упрощенный синтаксис для подобной записи:

```
a = a | b; // для |=
a = a & b; // для &=
```

Думаю, стало немного яснее, при чем тут равно. Далее попробуем разобраться, для чего же сами операторы `|` и `&`. Они называются **побитовое или** и **побитовое и** соответственно.

Оператор `|` берет побитовое представление операндов, и в результате выполнения этого оператора вы получите число, побитовое представление которого будет содержать единицы на тех позициях, **на которых хоть в одном из двух побитовых представлений операндов стояла единица**. Например:

```
4 | 5 = 5;
// или (в побитовом представлении)
100 | 101 = 101;
```

Заметим, что крайняя слева и справа единицы есть хоть в одном из двоичных представлений чисел, и поэтому после выполнения побитового или у нас есть число `101` (в бинарном представлении) или `5` (в десятичной системе счисления).

Оператор `&` берет побитовое представления операндов, и в результате выполнения этого оператора вы получите число, побитовое представление которого будет содержать единицы на тех позициях, **на которых в обоих побитовых представлениях операндов стояли единицы**. Например:

```
4 & 5 = 4;
// или (в побитовом представлении)
100 | 101 = 100;
```

Заметим, что осталась лишь одна единица, которая есть и в первом, и в правом операнде.

Ну и совсем вплотную подойдя к вашей задаче - `|` и `&` применяются обычно для работы с побитовыми флагами. Это сделано для экономии места. К примеру, у вас есть переменная размером 4 байта или 32 бита. В таком случае в этой переменной можно хранить аж `32` флага.

Чтобы добавить флаг, нужно применить `|`:

```
int flags = 0;
// Добавим флаг на третьей справа позиции, ведь бинарное представление 4 - 100
flags |= 0x4;
```

Чтобы проверить, есть ли флаг, нужно применить `&`:

```
// Бинарное и - по сути маска. И если на этой позиции была 1,
// то результат будет отличен от 0 и условие будет верным
if (flags & 0x4) {
    // сделать что-то
}
```

Как-то так. Почему же работает с равно? Все просто. С равно вы по сути стираете предыдущее состояние переменной с флагами, и передаете ей только 1 флаг вместе с равно. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил...

**UPD** кстати, в вашем случае `PORTB |= B00100000;` добавляет флаг, а потом `PORTB &= B00000000;` убирает его (что логично, ведь на той позиции, на которой мы поставили флаг, в `B00000000` единицы нет, и применив *и* мы по сути убрали флажок).

**UPD2** кстати, в чистом `c++` нет литералов вида `B00000000`, это фишка компилятора `arduino`. В `c++` начиная с версии `14` можно использовать запись вида `0b00000000`, чтобы представить бинарный литерал.

Comment: Короче я понял, фигня, которая в моём случае не пригодится, так?

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich ну с таким стремлением разобраться вы далеко не уедете. Данная тема находится довольно близко к азам, и без понимания вряд ли вы сможете писать что-то серьезное. Это кажется, что вроде много текста. А на самом деле все не так сложно, как кажется. Посмотрите в интернете про бинарные операторы, вероятно, в какой-нибудь статье вы найдете более понятное объяснение, чем я тут склепал на коленке.

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich пригодится, особенно в контексте встраиваемых систем (как Ардуино, например). Очевидное преимущество – экономия памяти.

Comment: @selya ну получается, мы присваиваем в PORT B00100000, которое получится и при просто равно, и при равно с "или". Тогда, зачем оно?

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich дело в том, что если в `PORT` уже был какой-то флаг, то мы при присвоении сотрем тот флаг. А при **или** мы лишь добавим еще один флаг.

Comment: @selya Тогда мне кажется, что тут "или" неуместен. Ведь я помигать светодиодом и всё - включить порт - выключить порт.

Comment: @selya, так можете объяснить, чем "ИЛИ" безопаснее "равно" в данном примере: https://hastebin.com/fupirobogo.scala

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich в смысле? Там же и комментарий написан, что **не меняет значения на выводах 0 и 1**

Comment: @selya, А может это для того, чтобы не поломать настройки в загрузчике? А то на каком нибудь порту будет тот же RX порт, а я возьму и поломаю его своим простым присваиванием.

Answer (score 5):

В **конкретном вашем** коде - да, это все равно. Потому что вам нужо, чтобы **вся переменная** получала то или иное значение.

Но при программировании всяких - особенно вот таких - вещей это очень нужные операции.

Представьте себе, что ваш `PORTB` отвечает сразу за 8 светодиодов. И вам нужно, не меняя остальные - которые светятся, пусть светятся, которые нет - так и остаются - помигать третьим.

Пусть `PORTB` был, ну, скажем, `B10011010` - четыре светодиода включены

В вашем варианте при присвоении

```
PORTB = B00000100
```

вы погасите их все, включив третий. Затем все выключите

```
PORTB = B00000000
```

А вот если сделать так:

```
PORTB = PORTB | B00000100
```

а затем

```
PORTB = PORTB & ~B00000100
```

переменная получит значения `B10011110`, а затем опять станет `B10011010`. Т.е. вы таким образом *способны работать с отдельными битами*.

Ну, а запись

```
PORTB = PORTB | B00000100
```

немного короче записывается как

```
PORTB |= B00000100
```

а

```
PORTB = PORTB & ~B00000100
```

как

```
PORTB &= ~B00000100
```

Если и это непонятно, то уж не знаю, что и делать...

Comment: Пожалуй, это действительно хорошее объяснение на пальцах. Странно, что вопрос был про `c++`) Кстати, `xor`-ом ведь тоже можно снять флаг, ведь так?

Comment: @selya Можно и xor'ом - вообще все операторы достаточно взаимозаменяемы - помнится, в студенческие времена на лабораторке на одном И-НЕ что угодно лепилось :)

Answer (score 0):

> Если заменить все эти |=, и &= на =, то всё будет работать точно также

Ничего подобного:

```
auto x{0x0E};
x &= 0x01;
assert(0 == x); 

auto y{0x0E};
y = 0x01;
assert(0x01 == y);
```

Заменить на равно можно, но с применением битового оператора:

```
auto z{0x0E};
z = z & 0x01;
assert(0x00 == z);
```

Comment: А можно так сказать "на пальцах" объяснить, зачем они?

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich Чтобы сэкономить на байтах кода (это было очень актуально в 70х). Так как запись `value &= 0x01;` получается короче чем `value = value & 0x01;`.

Comment: Так я не понял сам смысл написания |= вместо =. Просто у меня работает одинаково, или это просто для того, чтобы на байтах сэкономить и только? (= занимает больше байтов чем |=? Очень странно!

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich Это не работает одинаково, я же привел конкретный пример.

Comment: А его понял?...

Comment: Какой-то "auto" и "assert". Ничё не понимаю.

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich vtt хотел показать, что `&=` не тоже самое что `=`. И что на самом деле `x &= y` - это короткая запись `x = x & y`.

Answer (score 0):

Я хотел бы добавить к ранее сказанным простой пример.
Есть массив чисел, но не числа мне нужны, а нужен результат:  В какой позиции нечетные числа?

```
 int n[] = {1, 12, 33, 44, 5};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        n[i] &= 1;  // нечетным элементам присваиваем 1           
    }
```

- Тогда нечетным присвоится `1`, а четным `!1,` т.е. `0`
- А если вместо оператора `&=` использовать `|=`, тогда всем нечетным
  числам прибавится `1`, и будет массив выглядеть так `1, 13, 33, 45, 5`
- Если же просто присвоить, тогда все элементы будут единицами
  (естественно)...